# Can't get integer vertex attributes working in GLSL 1.5

Tags: opengl, attributes, integer, glsl

I'm using an OpenGL 3.2 context with GLSL 1.5 and for some reason integer attributes (of type int, uint, ivecX, or uvecX) are always being read as 0 in the vertex shader. I'm declaring them using:

```
in int name;
```

and I am binding the attributes using glVertexAttribIPointer (notice the I), and not glVertexAttribPointer (but that one doesn't work either). If I change them to be floats instead they work perfectly fine - the only code difference being the type in the vertex struct, the type in GLSL, and the IPointer function call instead of just Pointer. I'm not getting any errors or anything, they're just all 0. If I hard code integer values instead it works fine, and integer uniforms work fine. Also, built in integers like gl_VertexID work perfectly, just custom ones don't. I'm running an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870. I tried on another computer with a different GPU (unfortunately I'm not sure what GPU though, but it was different than mine) with the same results. Any ideas why this might be the case? Thanks.

EDIT: Actually it looks like they aren't 0, more likely they're random large uninitialized values... it's hard to tell since I can't find any ways to debug GLSL shaders. Anyway, some more info. Here is my vertex structure:

```
struct TileVertex {
    float pos[2];
    float uv[2];
    float width;
    float pad;
    int animFrames;
    int animFrameLength;
};
```

animFrames and animFrameLength are the two integer values I'm trying to send to the shader. My call to glVertexAttribIPointer for animFrames is the following:

```
glVertexAttribIPointer( attribute.location, attribute.typeSize, attribute.baseType, (GLsizei)stride, bufferOffset( bufOffset + attribOffset ) );
```

where:

```
attribute.location = 1 (as determined by OpenGL)
attribute.typeSize = 1 (since it's a single int, not a vector)
attribute.baseType = 5124, which is GL_INT
stride = 32, which is sizeof( TileVertex )
bufferOffset() converts to a void pointer relative to NULL
bufOffset = 0 (my vertices start at the beginning of the VBO), and
attribOffset = 24, which is the offset of animFrames in the TileVertex struct
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help so far guys. So I tried using transform feedback and things are making more sense now. If I set the int attrib's value to 1, in the shader it is:

```
1065353216 = 0x3F800000 = 1.0 in floating point
```

If I set it to 10, in the shader I get:

```
1092616192 = 0x41200000 = 10.0 in floating point
```

So it appears that the int attrib is being converted to float, then those bits are being interpreted as int in the shader, even though I'm specifying GL_INT and using IPointer instead of Pointer! As I understand it, IPointer is supposed to just leave the data in integer form and not convert it to a float.

EDIT:

Here are some more tests. For each test I am trying to pass the integer value 1 to an integer input in the shader:

```
glVertexAttribIPointer with GL_INT: shader values are 0x3F800000, which is 1.0 in floating point
```

seems to indicate that integer 1 is being converted to floating point 1.0, then being interpreted as an integer. This means that OpenGL either thinks that the source data is in floating point form (when it is actually in integer form), or it thinks that the shader inputs are floating point (when they are actually ints).

```
glVertexAttribIPointer with GL_FLOAT: shader values are valid but weird floating point values, such as 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 36.0... what the hell!?
```

no idea what this means. The only value I am passing is integer 1, so I can't figure out why each values would be different, or why they would be valid floats! My logic trying this was that if OpenGL was converting the integers to floats, maybe telling it that they were already float would avoid that, but apparently not.

```
glVertexAttribPointer with GL_INT: same result as glVertexAttribIPointer with GL_INT
```

this is the expected result. OpenGL converts the ints to floats, then passes them to the shader. This is what is supposed to happen since I didn't use the I version.

```
glVertexAttribPointer with GL_FLOAT: integer values 1 (the correct result)
```

this works because OpenGL 1) thinks the source data is in floating point form and 2) thinks the shader inputs are also in floating point form (they are actually int and int), so therefore does not apply any conversion, leaving int as int (or float as float, as it thinks). This works but it seems very hacky and unreliable, since I don't think there's a guarantee that CPU float to GPU float won't require a conversion (don't some GPUs use 16 bit floats? Maybe that's just pre-OpenGL 3 but still) - it just doesn't on my GPU.

Comment: Give us more information. Show us the call to glVertexAttribIPointer, and show us what data you are trying to pass.

Comment: You can debug vertex GLSL shaders by using Transform Feedback and reading the target buffer back to main memory.

Comment: Is your attribute index 0, by change? The first value you pass to glVertexAttribIPointer? What happens if you manually assign it to a different value? Also, what happens if you update your drivers? The fact that your card is capable of 3.3 (which ATI has drivers for), but you're getting 3.2 suggests that they're out of date.

Comment: I'm passing two integer attributes actually, so at least one of them is not index 0. Also, someone with an ATI HD 4870 told me they're having the same problem. Right now I'm setting up a 3.2 context, but I will try it with 3.3 (no particular reason for 3.2 anyway). In terms of updating drivers, that very well may be the problem. Unfortunately every time I try to update I get BSODs and lockups - sometimes even during the install! >:( But that's a different issue entirely, I read I have to update the VBIOS first (which honestly sounds terrifying). I'll give that another shot and report back.

Comment: OMG I'm not the only one ... Seeing the exact same thing: Hex numbers that represent the supposed int values as floats.

Answer (score 6):

For one of the shaders (can't remember which), you need to use the `varying` keyword.  Or maybe the `attribute` keyword.  Later versions of GLSL use `in` and `out` instead.

I think you need:

```
attribute int name;
```

for data going to the vertex shader, and

```
varying int name;
```

for data going from vertex shader to fragment shader.

Also make sure to enable the shader attribute with [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml).

---

I had some trouble getting `int` atributes working also, but what I did discover is that the `type` field (`GL_INT` or `GL_FLOAT` passed to `glVertexAttribPointer` matches the data passed to it, not the data type in the shader).  So I ended up using `glVertexAttribPointer` and `GL_INT` which converted `int` on my host to `float` in my shader, which is fine for me because my attribute was position data and needed to be transformed by a floating-point `vec2` anyway.

Probably you need `glVertexAttribIPointerEXT` to match your shader `int` attribute, and then also `GL_INT` if the host is supplying data as an `int` array.

Comment: In-Out are introduced by glsl 1.5, while attribute are deprecated from glsl 1.5.

Comment: @Luca: Thanks, can barely keep straight the version I use, never mind all the older ones.

Comment: @Luca: They were introduced in 1.30.

Comment: Ops... That's true (always confusing those two version, sigh)

Comment: I had a simular problem, and changing to glvertexattribIpointer solved the problem. The GL_INT was normalized even while the normalize parameter was GL_FALSE. (Radeon 7850, crimson)

Comment: I had a similar issue. The integers were converted directly to floats in the vertex shader, instead of staying as integers (as I wanted). So it gave me a bad, frustrating raw conversion error.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but maybe this information is still helpful:

`GLint` is [defined](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Type) as having a size of 32 bits,
but your `int` in C might as well be 64 bits.

This got me debugging for way too long.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which modern system do you know that has 64-bit `int`s?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml

`glVertexAttribPointer` will convert your input to float, even if the `normalized` argument is `false`.

`glVertexAttribIPointer` will only accept ints, and has no `normalized` parameter.